# Magento 1.x Product Detail Customize

Tags: magento-1, product-page

I want to completely change the design of the product detail page. The products that I added from the admin panel should be placed in that design. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The product you have added from admin panel, this is product add form, this from allow to add product for add it to cart, purchase product, etc.

But frontend products details page is allowed to add it to cart for purchase, etc. this is add to cart form.

Do you want to modify frontend add to cart form to backend product add form?

If so, you have to customize app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/catalog/product/view. phtml, if you are using custom theme, otherwise you have to customize magento default product details template.

Hope you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

First you are add the products for admin panel and show the fronted.

1) You are want to change page layout so you can change admin side.So you check this link

**https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-design.html**

2) You should take a look at the base `view.phtml` found at

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Copy the file into your custom theme at

```
app/design/frontend/{YourTheme}/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

and edit it to your specific needs.

Hope you will understand.

other you need more information.Please comment me.

Thanks ...